CocoaPods not installed or not in valid state. Flutter
Hey I saw this issus has faced others before and have some question and answers are available. But neither solution that mention not worked here
Launching lib/main_stage.dart on iPhone 15 Pro in debug mode...
Warning: CocoaPods is installed but broken. Skipping pod install.
  You appear to have CocoaPods installed but it is not working.
  This can happen if the version of Ruby that CocoaPods was installed with is different from the one being used to invoke it.
  This can usually be fixed by re-installing CocoaPods.
To re-install see https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation for instructions.

CocoaPods not installed or not in valid state.
Error launching application on iPhone 15 Pro.

flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.5, on macOS 14.4.1 23E224 darwin-arm, locale en-LK)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup for more details.
[!] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.3)
    ✗ CocoaPods installed but not working.
        You appear to have CocoaPods installed but it is not working.
        This can happen if the version of Ruby that CocoaPods was installed with is different from the one being used to invoke it.
        This can usually be fixed by re-installing CocoaPods.
      To re-install see https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation for instructions.
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[!] Android Studio (version 2023.3)
    ✗ Unable to find bundled Java version.
[✓] VS Code (version 1.89.1)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    ! Error: Browsing on the local area network for Dinesh's iPhone. Ensure the device is unlocked and attached with a cable or associated with the same local area network as this Mac.
      The device must be opted into Developer Mode to connect wirelessly. (code -27)
    ! Error: Browsing on the local area network for Saberion’s iPhone. Ensure the device is unlocked and attached with a cable or associated with the same local area network as this Mac.
      The device must be opted into Developer Mode to connect wirelessly. (code -27)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability

I have tried

flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter run
android studio invalidate clean
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods && sudo gem install cocoapods
open android studio on command line "open /Applications/Android\ Studio.app"
restart IDE, Editor
Restart laptop
create iOS folder separately

And also
I can run this application on android
Can run other Flutter Project
And dosen't change any configuration on cocopods

first cocoapod catchfile remove and unistall
Like this step
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
rm -rf ~/.cocoapods
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods
rm -rf ~/Library/Preferences/org.cocoapods.*
rm -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/CocoaPods
rm -rf Pods
rm -rf Podfile.lock
rm -rf *.xcworkspace

Then after cocoapod re install
like this steps
Homebrew
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"

ruby
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"

echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.zshrc
source ~/.zshrc

rbenv install 3.1.0
rbenv global 3.1.0

gem install cocoapods

pod setup


In a case where you ran flutter doctor and see the below message
    ✗ CocoaPods installed but not working.

STEP 1:
Confirm the directory it installed by running
which pod
My result was /Users/developer/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/bin//pod then copy /Users/developer/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/bin/
STEP 2:
Copy the PATH excluding //pod now I have copied /Users/developer/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/bin/ into my clipboard
STEP 3:
RUN
export PATH=/Users/developer/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/bin/:$PATH
STEP 4: (OPTIONAL)
You might need to restart your terminal
